# Clear selected items when one is clicked Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, materialize

I have a search form in which I am using Materializecss framework. In this form I have 2 multiple selection dropdowns, 1 is for provinces and 1 for districts, and of course is dynamic, when you select 1 province the districts are filled or removed from the other dropdown. My problem is that the first item of both is an option for "All Provinces/Districts" and I want to clear the selection when the users select that option, no matter if there were others provinces/districts select too.

```js
$('#province_select').on('change', function(e) {
  var value = $(this).val();
  var $selectDropdown = $("#district_select")
  $selectDropdown.html(' ');
  $selectDropdown.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", 0).text("All districts"));
  
  $(value).each(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < districts.length; i++) {
      if (districts[i][1] == this) {
        var districtValue = districts[i][2];
        $selectDropdown.append($("<option></option>").attr("value", districts[i][0]).text(districtValue));
      }
    }
  });

  $selectDropdown.trigger('contentChanged');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple="multiple" id="province_select" name="province_select[]">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Provinces</option>
  <option value="0">All Provinces</option>
  <?php printProvincesSelect();?>    
</select>
```

Comment: The UI is a bit weird. If there's a `multiple` select - why do you have an 'All' option contained in it? What's to stop someone selecting 'All' and a couple of other items, leaving some unchecked?. Does that mean they want all, or should we exclude the ones they didn't check? I'd suggest you remove the 'All' option and have a 'Select all' and 'Select none' button separate to the `select`.

Comment: Consider this scenario - The user selected "All districts" (selections are cleared as you asked), now what if user changes his/her mind & decides to choose only ONE of them again? How would the list populate again ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa I don't want to "unpopulate" the options or delete them, I just want them to be unselected when clicking "All Districts", but I think Rory's is the best approach.